# Can not use tensorflow in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, tensorflow

I can ran tensorflow in anaconda command line successfully, but when I ran it in pycharm, it complains for not finding tensorflow, but I do find it in the package of this python interpreter. Is there anything else I need to do ? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: It does find _a_ `tensorflow`, but it complains about it not having a `constant` attribute. For better searchability you should copy-paste the error message in the post instead of only showing a screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the console, your `.py` file is *also* called `tensorflow`, so when you do `import tensorflow as tf`, you end up trying to import things from the same file.

Rename your own file to something else, such as `tensorflow_test_1.py` or whatnot. :)

Comment: ...or use `from __future__ import absolute_imports` if there _is_ a sensible reason to use the same name